# Seeing if a value is present in a dictionary

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to see if an item is located in a dictionary values.

My attempt:

```js
var inventory_needed = [
    { section: "hardware",          supplies: "hammers"                       },
    { section: "plumbing",          supplies: "pipes"                         },
    { section: "garden",            supplies: "grass seeds"                   },
    { section: "cleaning supplies", supplies: ["hand sanitizer", "detergent"] },
    { section: "appliances",        supplies: ["fridges", "dishwashers"]      } 
];

incoming_item = "hand sanitizer";

inventory_needed.forEach(function(item) {
    if(item.supplies.includes(incoming_item)) {
        console.log(incoming_item + 'is on the way');
    }
    else{
        console.log('nothing is on the way');
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `)` on the last line... should be `})`. Just a typo here in your question or is your actual code like that too?

Comment: `const result = inventory_needed.filter(o => o.supplies.includes(incoming_item))` you can test if the length of result is > 0, and see which items match.

Comment: Be careful with that data structure. I would suggest that all `supplies` should always be an array, even with only a single item. Your current code will return false positives for something like `supplies: "hand sanitizer for snakes"`

Comment: With your design, you should check if `supplies` is array first.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/53arLzm6/ see if this code works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your search this way:

```
if (inventory_needed.some(item => item.supplies.includes(incoming_item))) {
   console.log(incoming_item + ' is on the way');
} else {
   console.log('nothing is on the way');
}
```

This will only ever output once. It's not clear whether or not you want the `is on the way` message to be able to print multiple times.

[Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) will let you run a `true`/`false` check for each element in the list, and returns whether or not any of them were `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your supplies array consist of both string and array, I suggest this below logic for you.

**Logic**

- `map` through the array and generate list of supplies.
- `Array.flat` the array to make the array uni directional. I used [`Array.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to combine both [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- Generate the unique elements from this array using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- Search for the target element in this `Set` array using [`Set.has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has).

**Working Code**

```js
const inventory_needed = [
    { section: "hardware", supplies: "hammers" },
    { section: "plumbing", supplies: "pipes" },
    { section: "garden", supplies: "grass seeds" },
    { section: "cleaning supplies", supplies: ["hand sanitizer", "detergent"] },
    { section: "appliances", supplies: ["fridges", "dishwashers"] }
];
const incoming_item = "hand sanitizer";
const uniqueSuppliesList = new Set(inventory_needed.flatMap((item) => item.supplies));
uniqueSuppliesList.has(incoming_item) ? console.log(incoming_item + 'is on the way') : console.log('nothing is on the way');
```

Comment: Why convert the `Set` back to an array? You can just use `set.has(incoming_item)` which is actually a quicker lookup

Comment: Also, how on Earth did you add an answer 11 mins after the question was closed?